# Chatbot with IBM Watson - How to validate date input?

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm creating a chatbot with IBM Watson. Imagining the scenario where the user enters a date, how can I save this date and validate if it's in a format that chatbot understands? Should i use entity or slot?

PS: my chatbot should understand formats like 07/2019; 07/19; 07-19; but should not understand format July 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watson Assistant has a `@sys-date` system entity that allows the end user to say the date in a whole range of formats. For example "two weeks from now".

It stores it in a format which you can then reformat to any date structure you wish using [reformatDateTime()](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-dates-reformatDateTime).

From a conversation point of view this is the best option. If you are going to use a fixed format, then its better to have a mini-form in your UI.

If you want to ignore all that, then you can use a pattern entity to build the acceptable regular expressions you want. This is better than checking there and then with just a normal regular expression.